# Dynamically assigning variable names JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to dynamically assign variable names using the user's input. For example:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   var newVariableName = //input.value;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Scratch Cat

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: What would you like to do with it? Theoretically you could do it by using the global object, though it might be easier to have a dictionary object that matches the given names and values

Comment: Why don't you just use an array/object?

Comment: You can add new properties to the `window` object with dynamic names: `window[dynamicallyGeneratedString] = input.value;`

Comment: So I'm planning to make these variables into objects, then push them onto an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in JavaScript is an object. The way JavaScript works, you can add properties to objects in two ways:

1. Specify them the fixed way (e.g. `obj.propertyName = 'Value'`)
2. Specify them using array notation (e.g. `obj[propertyName] = 'Value'`). In this case, note that propertyName is a string value.

In both cases, the result will be exactly the same. You could retrieve those properties likewise, e.g. `obj.propertyName` and `obj[propertyName]`. Both will return `'Value'`.

In your case, @LuudJacobs's suggestion about using the window object will most probably do the trick...

Comment: Yes but you can't have the same name for different objects in an array. It crashes.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array in which the keys will be the input values and the value would be anything you want.

html

```
<form>

<input type="text" value="demo1" class="example"><br />
<input type="text" value="demo2" class="example"><br />
<input type="text" value="demo3" class="example">

</form>
```

js
First you declare array

```
var a = new Array();
```

Then you use for loop to assign key names to array which will be the input values

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    a[x[i].value] = x[i].value;
}
```

Finally you can use those key names to access the values

```
alert(a['demo1'] + ' ' +a['demo2'] + ' ' + a['demo3']);
```

Here is a link to an example
https://jsfiddle.net/309fpsjn/1/

```html
<html>
<form>

<input type="text" value="demo1" class="example"><br />
<input type="text" value="demo2" class="example"><br />
<input type="text" value="demo3" class="example">

</form>
<script>
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".example");

var a = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    a[x[i].value] = x[i].value;
}

alert(a['demo1'] + ' ' +a['demo2'] + ' ' + a['demo3']);

</script>
</html>
```